# solve_ivp gets stuck, forever, with this problem

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, numerical-integration

I'm trying to solve a system of differential equations with `scipy.integrate.solve_ivp`. The system depends on a *real independent variable* **t** and the *dependent variables*, **c<sub>n</sub>(t)**-s are *complex* in general. The catch is, the solver always gets stuck, no matter the dimension of the system (determined by `n_max`). Here's the setup:

```
# Constants
from scipy.constants import hbar as h_
n_max = 2
t_max = 1

# The derivative function
def dcdt(t, c):
    return (-1.0j/h_)*((V_mat*np.exp(1.0j*w_mat*t)) @ c)

# Initial conditions
c_0 = np.zeros(n_max, dtype = complex)
c_0[0] = 1.0

#  Solving the deal
t = np.linspace(0, t_max, 10)
c = solve_ivp(dcdt, [0, t_max], c_0, t_eval = t)
```

And there it goes, doesn't ever stop running.
Here are sample matrices `V_mat` and `w_mat`:

```
>>> V_mat
array([[1.0000000e-09, 1.8008153e-56],
       [1.8008153e-56, 1.0000000e-09]])

>>> w_mat
array([[      0.        , -156123.07053024],
       [ 156123.07053024,       0.        ]])
```

As you will notice, `V_mat` and `w_mat` are 2-D square matrices of dimension `n_max`.

Is the problem tied to large/very small values in the matrices? Or is it something to do with complex values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I had already guessed, the problem *is* tied to large values in the differential equations I'm trying to solve, in particular, due to `-1.0j/h_` in

```
def dcdt(t, c):
    return (-1.0j/h_)*((V_mat*np.exp(1.0j*w_mat*t)) @ c)
```

where `h_ = 1.054e-34` is the *reduced Planck's constant*. Rescaling the equation and removing `h_` fixes the problem.